# Is there any way to give all users access to one blog in a multisite network without using a plugin?

Tags: multisite, users, user-roles, hacks

I know there are various plugins out there to help with multisite user management, but we have a policy of avoiding plugins for a) overzealous security policies, and b) interfering with our already heavily-modified WordPress installation (this has bit us before).

Also, simply adding all ~10,000 users to this one blog seems inelegant. That's a *lot* of new entries in `wp_usermeta`.

Is there any filter or action I can intercept to say "if this is blog X, then let any registered user through"? The `admin_init` action hook lets me *restrict* users according to arbitrary criteria, but I don't know how to let them through.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter `get_blogs_of_user` and add this particular blog to the returned list. Pseudo-code, not tested:

```
add_filter( 'get_blogs_of_user', 'add_special_blog', 10, 3 );

function add_special_blog( $blogs, $user_id, $all )
{
    $new_blog = get_blog_details( $special_blog_id );

    $blogs[ $special_blog_id ] = (object) array(
    'userblog_id' => $special_blog_id,
    'blogname'    => $new_blog->blogname,
    'domain'      => $new_blog->domain,
    'path'        => $new_blog->path,
    'site_id'     => $new_blog->site_id,
    'siteurl'     => $new_blog->siteurl,
    'archived'    => 0,
    'spam'        => 0,
    'deleted'     => 0
    );

    return $blogs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, awesome idea (didn't know about that filter!), but doesn't seem to work. Whereas before, I got the message 'You attempted to access the "Special Blog" dashboard, but you do not currently have privileges on this site. If you believe you should be able to access... blah blah' After using this filter I get "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page." Also I realized that these stuffed-in users probably won't have permissions to edit and publish posts. This method will probably be more trouble than it's worth... might just have to add every user to this blog. Thanks anyway